# Ceiling LED light emits very dim light when switch is off!

Tags: led, lamp

I have overhead ceiling LED light fixtures.

When I turn on **Main Switch** of the house, I see the LED starts emitting very dim light ( have to look for a 3-4 second to perceive) even when LED's **switch** is **off**!

Is that normal or I need to check it out by an electrician ?

Comment: For more details please check [this](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/138847/led-bulb-still-emits-light-when-turned-off) out.

Comment: Is the light switch a normal on-off type or is there any kind of electronic switching such as a remote or dimmer?

Comment: @transistor Normal On/off

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two typical reasons for this:

1. The Phosphorous used in the led is experiencing chemiluminescence, a cold chemical reaction that produces light. The Phosphor is normally used to be give leds their white color through photo luminescent reaction, reacting to photons of a different wavelength, but it can glow in the dark without that.
2. The light bulb is on a circuit with a switched neutral wire, instead of a switched hot wire. This means that the AC voltage on the hot wire can still slightly power the leds and/or the capacitors in the light bulb, leading to a **few milli or micro amps of current** to flow through ultra efficient leds, lighting them up.

You could test this by putting the bulb in a switched lamp with a non-polarized power connector plugged in one way, and then flip the connector around the other way. One way should result in completely off leds.

Comment: I am not able to understand the term - switched hot / neutral wire. What I know is there are two wires Live and Neutral connected with any appliance. But I didn't understand - switched to neutral.

Comment: @mit the switched wire is the wire that is being disconnected when the switch is turned off. So a Switched Neutral cuts the neutral side of the circuit, leaving the hot or live side connected. You normally want to switch the hot side.

Comment: So in my case the probability of the lights switched to neutral, and this leads to hot connected even after **switching off** . And to rectify this i need to reverse the **Line** and **neutral** from my current setup. Right?

Answer (score 0):

Some switches have a neon illumination to help find it in the dark; if so it will be connected ACROSS the open switch forming the leakage path mentioned above. No problem as long as the load is much higher than the neon needs, but can cause a CFL or LED to flicker or light dimly.